# Uncaught ReferenceError: Butt is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are a ton of these on the site already, but nothing seems to be the culprit for my issue. I'm trying to implement a django module into my project, but I ran into a snag when the provided JS didn't work. Assuming that perhaps something was broken, I tried to modify it to work; when that failed, I went to the simplest function I could and still had no luck.

I went ahead and removed everything from jqchat.js and replaced it with the simple function below. I also tried calling Butt() from inside and outside $(document).ready(), with no success either way. Also, I know that jqchat is being imported because there's no 404 (if I change it to jqchattttt.js I get an error).

Any ideas? jquery works and the bootstrap functions work, but nothing from jqchat.js wants to work.

excerpt of base.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jqchat/jqchat.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Butt();
        //InitChatWindow("{% url jqchat_ajax 1 %}", null);
    });
</script>
```

jqchat/jqchat.js

```
function Butt() {
    console.log('butts');
}
```

Comment: interesting function name there.

Comment: Can you confirm that jqchat.js is being loaded?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache recently?

Comment: @BabakNaffas Yes, as I mentioned, the script does not 404 out and I have no idea how it wouldn't be loaded aside from that.

Comment: @JohnKoerner I have not, but making other changes to the file seems to have an effect.